# Quectel BG96 MQTT publish error

Tags: arduino, mqtt, at-command, gprs, thingsboard

I'm try to publish my data to ThingsBoard server i use this types of AT commands

```
AT+QIACT=1
OK
AT+QMTOPEN=1,"demo.thingsboard.io",1883
OK
AT+QMTCONN=1,"demo.thingsboard.io","MY_ACCESS_TOKEN",""
OK
AT+QMTPUB=1,0,0,0,"v1/devices/me/telemetry"
>{"temperature":35.00,"humidity":80.00}  // MY_POST_DATA This line hanging my module
```

All AT commands response is ok But i finally enter MY_POST_DATA the module doesn't provide no response hanging the previous command.. and i check my ThinksBoard data never post telemetry..

Please help any one how can i fix this problem and publish MQTT server.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Get hold of the official AT command documentation for the modem (Quectel BG96 I assume?). It should document how the `AT+QMTPUB` command behaves and what it expects. Everything else is just guessing. The manufacturer should provide this, and if not you should demand to get one.

...

**Step 873**, *when you have exhausted absolutely all possible ways of getting hold of the official AT command documentation for the modem*: You can try my *guess* that the command behaves similar to other commands that read arbitrary length user data, most notably `AT+CMGS` which sends SMS messages, which expect a Ctrl-Z (ascii value 26) as an end of data indicator.

Comment: Thanks for helping hlovdal.. I used Ctrl-Z command after posting data my response get +QMTPUB: 1,0,0
publish ok but Server still no update my data don't posted on the telemetry

Answer (score 0):

+QMTPUB: 1,0,0 simply mean that BG96 has successfully published and your broker (thingsboard) have also acknowledged publication of message.

If you can't see data on broker, then please check if the topic you are publishing is correct or not.
It may happen you are publishing to another topic (or to a different PATH).
Ask 'thingsboard' for help regarding proper topic.

Comment: I publish the data on same topic via ESP8266 it's working fine. but the BG96 AT command does't working i use different topics to publish but  the same issue still there. how can i solve this problem how i get help in (thingsboard server).

Comment: You can simply solve the issue by contacting 'thingsboard'. Go to their website and ask your query through 'contact us' section. They will guide you further. I had experienced same kind of issue in 'assetwolf portal' broker. They helped me to solve it.